# Hide developer options is enable in android?

Tags: android, root, android-kernel

I am trying to find programmatic way in android to :

- Hide Mock Location **[without root]**
- Hide that developer option is On **[without root]**

it is possible programmatically speaking ? Thanks i know this question is pointless unless i try something , but there are no such questions asked before so no solution !!

**Edit:**

There is a feature called `Mock Location` in `Developer options(when enabled)` , hiding it means no other application could detect that i have enabled `Mock Location` option, same goes for `Hiding Developer option enable` in which i want to restrict other application to check status of `developer options` that it is ON or OFF

Comment: You may have to jump through some hurdles to do this ... I immediately think doing something like this requires creating a custom ROM

Comment: Please explain, in detail, what "Hide Mock Location" and "Hide that developer option is On" mean.

Comment: @apelsoczi apps like Xposed and many other application are doing this in marshmallow i heard , but not confirmed

Comment: Why the heck did you tag `pokemon-go`?

Comment: I'm gonna go ahead and assume you're trying to cheat at Pokemon Go without them finding out...

Comment: @DannyBuonocore who don't ? well i'm just curious about why it's solution is not found yet that's it

Comment: It's definitely been done before. I know several people who have accomplished this.

Comment: yes its done but works only on ROOT android why can't it work on UNROOTED devices